# how can I get the access token needed for ms graph

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

when registering an app in azure to access mail using ms graph the callback URL is optional, when I try this code it doesn't seem to get the correct token because I get an error 400 when using the token to access office 365. But if I copy the token from the ms graph developer page and use that token it works.

```
tenant_id = "xxxxx"
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenant_id + '/oauth2/v2.0/token'

    # Makes a POST request to the token endpoint to get an access token
def get_access_token():
  payload = {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
  }
  response = requests.post(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, data=payload)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.json()['access_token']
  else:
    print('Failed to get access token:')
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
    return None
```

Can someone show me the correct way to get the token?

Comment: The meaning of 400 status code is bad request which means the request which the client is trying to make is not correct. Please share the token endpoint as well.

Comment: I have updated the code with my endpoint

Comment: I used to use javascript to send ajax request to this endpoint and try to get access token but failed, I got cors issue that time. the error message doesn't make sense in this scenario, we need to use msal

Answer (score 1):

The request you used is correct, if you using tools like postman to call this request, you will get correct access token. But it doesn't mean that you can using any kind of programming language to send such a http request to get the access token. Using programming language required to use MSAL([microsoft authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)).

In your scenario, you used python and require to generate access token for application permission, so here's [the sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/blob/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithSecret/confidential_client_secret_sample.py) for it.

```
"""
The configuration file would look like this (sans those // comments):
{
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Name_Here",
    "client_id": "your_client_id",
    "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
        // For more information about scopes for an app, refer:
        // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate"
    "secret": "The secret generated by AAD during your confidential app registration",
        // For information about generating client secret, refer:
        // https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Client-Credentials#registering-client-secrets-using-the-application-registration-portal
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
}
You can then run this sample with a JSON configuration file:
    python sample.py parameters.json
"""

import sys  # For simplicity, we'll read config file from 1st CLI param sys.argv[1]
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal


# Optional logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

config = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential=config["secret"],
    # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
                       # You can learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
                       # https://msal-python.rtfd.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
    )

# The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
result = None

# Firstly, looks up a token from cache
# Since we are looking for token for the current app, NOT for an end user,
# notice we give account parameter as None.
result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=None)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, ).json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
```

Comment: When running the code @Tiny Wang I get this error..

Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

And this even if I have granted admin consent for application and the app itself... Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: `Insufficient privileges` means lack of api permission, but you said you already gave it. so I'm afraid you need to check it. the graph api endpoint in the code snippet I pasted above is `v1.0/users` which required `User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`, so have you given all these api permissions? By the way they should be `application` type on permissions, not `delegated` @MTplus

Comment: Yes User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All are added with application type, But the user rights might not be accessible direvtly when you add them, there is a slight delay and I now get a list of users

Comment: now you can get the list of users, then the issue solved right and the question can be ended?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the access token using OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow:

[image]

Please check this documnentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token

hope this helps